# How to traverse a directory tree, running a command on each file there?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, file-organization

Using `cmd.exe` after a cursory look though of the output of `help for`:

Command: `FOR /R \Music %file IN (*.flac *.wav *.aif) DO C:flac.exe -f -8 %file`
Response: `%file was unexpected at this time.`

Command: `FOR /R \Music %file% IN (*.flac *.wav *.aif) DO C:flac.exe -f -8 %file%`
Response: `%file% was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

Replace:

**`"c:\Full_Path_to\Music"`** to full path to your **`\Music`** folder

**`@C:\Where\FLAC\Are\flac.exe`**  to full path to **`Flac.exe`**

```cmd
for %i in (flac wav aif)do for /f %F in ('where /r "c:\Full_Path_to\Music" "*.%i"')do C:\Where\FLAC\Are\flac.exe -f -8 "%F"
```

Or, for bat file:

```cmd
@for %%i in (flac wav aif)do @for /f %%F in ('where /r "c:\Full_Path_to\Music" "*.%%i"')do @C:\Where\FLAC\Are\flac.exe -f -8 "%%F"
```

Also, you can try this:

```cmd
cd /d "C:\Full_Path_to\Music" && for /r %%i in (*.flac,*.wav,*.aif)do @"C:\Where\FLAC\Are\flac.exe" -f -8 "%%~i"
```